# Perl Regex for getting version numbers from file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that looks like the following:

```
app.version.code=1
app.version.major=1
app.version.minor=0
app.version.buildnumber=0
```

I want to run a Perl script that will print out `<app.version.major>.<app.version.minor>.<app.version.buildnumber>`. In this case it would print out 1.0.0. I'm very very rusty with Perl right now and am having trouble creating a regex and script to give me this. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, what you expect it to do, and describe what doesn't work.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are after. Do you want code.minor.buildnumber, or major.minor.buildnumber, or some other permutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat > ver.txt
app.version.code=1
app.version.major=1
app.version.minor=0
app.version.buildnumber=0
^d

cat> ver.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($ma,$mi,$bi)=(0,0,0);
while(<>){ 
  if(/^app\.version\.(.*)$/) { 
    if( $1 =~ /^major=(\d+)$/ ){$ma=$1}
    elsif( $1 =~ /minor=(\d+)$/ ){$mi=$1}
    elsif( $1 =~ /buildnumber=(\d+)$/ ) {$bi=$1}
  }
} 

print "$ma.$mi.$bi\n";
^d

./ver.pl < ver.txt 
1.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I was forgetting the boolean condition :S

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
perl -F= -lane '$h{$F[0]}=$F[1]; 
  END { print join ".", @h{ glob "app.version.{major,minor,buildnumber}" } }' filename
```

Comment: Thanks, you solution is elegant. Due to time sensitivity I gave it to first poster.

Answer (score 0):

VersionXtrct.pl:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;

    my $inFile = $ARGV[0];

    open(INHANDLE, "<$inFile") || die("Could not open file");

    my @fileLines = <INHANDLE>;

    my $fileText = join("", @fileLines);

    my $major;
    my $minor;
    my $build;

    if($fileText =~ m/app\.version\.major=(.+)\n/) { $major = $1; }

    if($fileText =~ m/app\.version\.minor=(.+)\n/) { $minor = $1; }

    if($fileText =~ m/app\.version\.buildnumber=(.+)\n/) { $build = $1; }

    my $version = $major.".".$minor.".".$build;

print "\nversion = ".$version;

    exit(0);
```

Assuming your data is in a file called input.txt, run:

```
VersionXtrct.pl input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed non-arbitrary order in my previous try. This should work as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.010;

my %version;

while (<DATA>) {
  given ($_) {
    $version{major}       = $1 when /app\.version\.major=(\d+)/;
    $version{minor}       = $1 when /app\.version\.minor=(\d+)/;
    $version{buildnumber} = $1 when /app\.version\.buildnumber=(\d+)/;
  }
}

say join ".", @version{qw/major minor buildnumber/};

__DATA__
app.version.code=1
app.version.major=1
app.version.minor=0
app.version.buildnumber=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %ver;

while (<>) {
    $ver{$1} = $2 if /(major|minor|number)=(\d+)$/;
}

print "$ver{major}.$ver{minor}.$ver{number}\n";
```

Output on your data set:

```
1.0.0
```